# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1+x} =1.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1+x} =1.$$

Here's how I started my proof,

$$|f(x)−1| = \left|\frac{1}{1+x} -1 \right| = \frac{x}{1+x} < \frac{\delta}{1+x}$$

I don't know how to continue now.

Comment: We can assume $|x|<1/2$ that gives a bound on $\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x|<\frac12$, then $1+x\in\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$; in particular, $1+x>\frac12$, and therefore $\left|\frac x{1+x}\right|<2|x|$. So, take $\delta=\min\left\{\frac12,\frac\varepsilon2\right\}$, and then\begin{align}|x|<\delta&\implies\left|\frac x{1+x}\right|<2|x|\text{ (since $|x|<\frac12$)}\\&\implies\left|\frac x{1+x}\right|<\varepsilon\end{align}(since $|x|<\frac\varepsilon2$).

Comment: why do u assume that |x|< 1/2? it means that delta=1/2?

Comment: $x$ is tending to $0$. We can assume that $|x|$ is as small as we wish when computing the limit.

Comment: No, it does **not** mean that $\delta=\frac12$. As I wrote, $\delta=\min\left\{\frac12,\frac\varepsilon2\right\}$. I started with $|x|<\frac12$ because then $\left|\frac x{1+x}\right|<2|x|$. And now it is quite easy to see which $\delta$ I should pick so that $|x|<\delta\implies\left|\frac x{1+x}\right|<\varepsilon$.